# Acoustic energy

Tags: thermodynamics, waves, acoustics

Let's Assume that I'm sitting in a hypothetical container (room) whose 6 walls are PERFECTLY AND IDEALLY rigid and also are PERFECTLY reflective. Now if I start speaking anything in this room and so start generating acoustic pressure waves,there would be an inflow of acoustic energy in the room coming from my body's chemical energy. Also,I keep speaking forever, so that there's continuous inflow of energy forever. Now if this energy is not absorbed by the walls of the room and are just being reverberated Around in the room itself, then can I expect an infinite energy density in this volume of space after infinite time?

Comment: At some point you won't have more energy to speak...

Comment: Oh come on...the source doesn't necessarily has to be a person...could be a speaker as well

Comment: Depends on energy source... If its infinite then possible

Comment: The point is that if energy is not absorbed then as long  as you have energy to add, energy will be added. As Shubham says, it is all about the source then, since everything else of the surroundings is ideal

Comment: Well then, what should I expect to happen in the room after A long while?does the room become heated?or the amplitude becomes so large that I go deaf?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Even if the walls are perfectly reflective, the air needs to be compressed and expanded so the acoustic waves propagate across the room. Some of the acoustic energy in this process becomes heat due to the expansion and contraction of air molecules. So, your room would also need to be perfectly thermally insulated. What this would mean is that, eventually, the room temperature would increase. Then of course is the other limitation in your question: for you to be able to speak forever, you need an infinite supply of chemical energy ;).